# Is it okay if i read the tasbih different times in different sujud or ruku?

Tags: salat, sujud, ruku

let's say in 1 Rakat 2 sujud.
Usually, I repeat the tasbih 3 or 5 times on each sujud. So, if in the first sujud I repeated 5 times, in the 2nd one I repeated 3 times accidentally, is it a problem? Do I have to perform Sajda Sahw for that?

Comment: What exactly you mean by tasbeeh?

Comment: SUBHAANA RABBIYAL A'LA

Answer (score 1):

It is Sunnah to recite it thrice. Odd is better than even. Other than that, I don't know of any ruling preventing you from reciting it a different number of times. At least not in the Hanafi madhab. Others may differ.

Allah knows best.

Comment: I don't think that reciting anything in ruku' or sujud is fard even in the Hanafi maddhab. However the acts of sujud and ruku' are fard as Allah ordered them in the qur'an.

Comment: I looked up, and you're right. Jazakallah Ghair for pointing out my mistake.